# Javascript to outline a png image?

Tags: javascript

I have a map which is a png file. I use getBoundingClientRect() with 2 div containers to check for overlapping divs througout my game. (Works fine to check for collison).

I was wondering if it's possible to outline a specific part of an image or **wherever the transparency starts** so I can then add a onclick event to that part of the div so the user cannot click outside of the map.

[image]

Hope this kind of makes sense.. If you need any more information let me know. Thanks

Comment: use the <area> tag to make an image map. you can dynamically build one based on the image data, but that's going to be a lot of math and looping over the getImageData() pixel values, which is not to be taken lightly...

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: My effort is over 100 small div boxes that are outlined aroud the map with fixes positions and when a user clicks on it, it returns false. That is unitutive and would need to be done for each new map with their different layouts. I'm looking for something that just outlines everything transparent or when transparency starts on a .png map, that would be way faster and I hope it's possible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/

You add an area tag with the coords you need, then you can apply something over it. I recommend you this plugin since it's very powerful, easy to use.